# How do I decompile my appconfig.json

Tags: xamarin, apk, app-config, reverse-engineering, api-key

I'm using Xamarin and I have all my API keys stored in my PCL in a file called appconfig.json

When the APK is generated, where are my API keys stored?

Can somebody take this APK and decompile to get the contents of this file?

I know is possible, but I'm on a mac and so don't have access to windows tools.

Can somebody walk me through these steps to read the contents of appconfig.json once its compiled? This is only so that I can prove it can be done -- which I know it can, its just taking me too long.  Thanks!

Comment: Im not really sure actually, we're we're MVVM iOC container and initialize that on the native layer during OnCreate() but the appconfig.json is coming from the PCL. When I open the Zip of my APK I can go to assemblies -> dll.config but I don't think thats what I'm looking for

Comment: We're just reading the contents of the JSON file at runtime

Comment: Ah, I see here we're embedding it as an assembly resource and reading it like this -> 'var resourceNames = assembly.GetManifestResourceNames();'

Comment: It is recommended to ask questions about Reverse Engineering in [Reverse Engineering Stack Exchange](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So lets assume I have this json file flagged as `EmbeddedResource` within one of my application's assemblies (call `SomeLibrary`):

```
{
    "Password": "SushiHangover",
    "Logging": {
        "Debug": {
            "LogLevel": {
                "Default": "Warning"
            }
        },
        "Console": {
            "LogLevel": {
                "Default": "Warning"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I archive & publish an `.apk`.

#### Extract apk contents

```
unzip com.sushihangover.SomeApp.apk -d foobar
```

#### Search for all embedded resources:

Use `ikdasm` to search for embedded resources:

```
find . -name "*.dll" -print0 | xargs -n 1 -0 -J % ikdasm % | grep .mresource

.mresource public charinfo.nlp
.mresource public collation.core.bin
.mresource public collation.tailoring.bin
.mresource public mscorlib.xml
.mresource public SomeLibrary.appconfig.json
```

Found the `appconfig.json` resource, so we can use `ikdasm` again to get from details.

#### SomeLibrary.appconfig.json Details:

```
ikdasm assemblies/SomeLibrary.dll
```

#### Results in:

```
~~~~
69 62 72 61 72 79 00 00 ) // ...SomeLibrary..
  .hash algorithm 0x00008004
  .ver 1:0:0:0
}
.mresource public SomeLibrary.appconfig.json
{
  // Offset: 0x00000000 Length: 0x00000116
  // WARNING: managed resource file SomeLibrary.appconfig.json created
}
.module SomeLibrary.dll
// MVID: {3100E9F8-3BB0-4E49-ADC7-33B284FCCFAE}
.imagebase 0x00400000
~~~~
```

#### `string` the assemblies to get the details:

```
cd foobar
find . -name "*.dll" -print0 | xargs -n 1 -0 -J % strings %

~~~
mscoree.dll
!This program cannot be run in DOS mode.
.text
`.rsrc
@.reloc
    "Password": "SushiHangover",
    "Logging": {
        "Debug": {
            "LogLevel": {
                "Default": "Warning"
            }
        },
        "Console": {
            "LogLevel": {
                "Default": "Warning"
            }
        }
    }
BSJB
v4.0.30319
~~~~
```

Comment: Wow, @SushiHangver, you are a SUSHI NINJA. This is exactly what I was looking for this is awesome. Thank you!!

Comment: @stepheaw No problem... 

Answer (score 0):

for Android apps, you can include arbitrary files in the APK as [Assets](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/application_fundamentals/resources_in_android/part_6_-_using_android_assets/)

```
string config;

AssetManager assets = this.Assets;
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader (assets.Open ("appconfig.json")))
{
    config = sr.ReadToEnd ();
}
```

Comment: I don't think this is what I'm asking. I'm asking if theres a file called appconfig.json in my app, where do the contents get saved to at compile time? you're saying this file will get saved under Assets?

Comment: You are asking how to include an arbitrary file in the APK at build time.  The answer is to use an Android Asset

Comment: I'm asking if somebody can get decompile the APK to see a JSON file included in my PCL